# jQuery Code not working in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code which shows couple radio buttons on click. This works fine in ie and firefox but does not work in chrome or safari even though the alert works.

```
function toggle_question_types(){
        if(jQuery('input[name="question"]:checked').val()==1){              
                        jQuery("#abc").show();
                        alert('this works');
                }       
    }    
    toggle_question_types();
    jQuery('input[name="question"]').change(function(){
        toggle_question_types();
    });
```

forgot to put the } before toggle_question_types(); but this also not working still.

Comment: Is the console in Chrome reporting any errors?

Comment: I cannot believe that that infininitely recursive function works in any browser, unless they're throwing some exception you're not noticing.  The function calls itself unconditionally, and will therefore cause a stack overflow.

Comment: show us the HTML that goes with this

Answer (score 1):

You never closed the function definition (insert a `}` before the explicit call to `toggle_question_types`), so I'm not entirely sure how it works in any browsers without infinitely recursing.